# varying classification threshold to produce ROC curves.

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

How can I vary classification threshold to produce ROC curves. I am new to R and I wanted to classify in different algorithm. Since the accuracy of ROC plot is high I wanted to change the threshold and try.

I wanted to know how to vary threshold ? What is the appropriate threshold value ?

Answer (score 9):

For an overall explanation of how ROC curves are computed consider this excellent answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105577/112731

To your question: first, if you want to compare different approaches, comparing their ROC curves and area under curve (AUC) values directly will be a good idea, as those give you overall information about how powerful your approaches are on your problem.

Second: you will need to choose a threshold *appropriate for your goal*. The tradeoff with this is that you will need to decrease one of the TPR (true positive rate, or sensitivity), *or* TNR (true negative rate, or specificity) in order to increase the other - there is no way around this$^1$. So, depending on your problem, you might e.g. happen to need a low false positive rate (FPR = 1 - TNR), which in turn will require you to have a high TNR - so this will definitely depend on details of your problem.

Having said this, to choose a threshold you will usually look at both the ROC curve and the distribution of TPR and TNR over the threshold. Those should provide the required information for you to choose a reasonable tradeoff. As you want to do this in R, here's a minimal example of how this could look like:

```
# example 2-class data and model training
library(caret)
d <- iris[51:150,]
d[,5] <- factor(d[,5])
model <- train(x = d[,c(1,3)], y = d[,5], method = 'lda', metric = 'ROC', trControl=trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', number = 10, repeats = 10, savePredictions = T, classProbs = T, summary = twoClassSummary))

# plot roc using pROC package
library(pROC)
myRoc <- roc(predictor = model$pred$versicolor, response = model$pred$obs, positive = 'versicolor')
plot(myRoc)
```

[image: ROC]

```
# look at TPR and TNR distribution over threshold
matplot(data.frame(myRoc$sensitivities, myRoc$specificities), x = myRoc$thresholds, type='l', xlab = 'threshold', ylab='TPR, TNR')
legend('bottomright', legend=c('TPR', 'TNR'), lty=1:2, col=1:2)
```

[image: TPR TNR over threshold]

So in this example, for about equal TPR and TNR, you would want to choose a threshold around 0.5. If you would want to e.g. have very low FPR you would want to choose a lower threshold instead. After choosing a `threshold`, you can use the predicted class probabilities to immediately determine the predicted class:

```
label <- ifelse(model$pred$versicolor > threshold, 'versicolor', 'virginica')
confusionMatrix(label, model$pred$obs, positive = 'versicolor')

    Confusion Matrix and Statistics

                Reference
    Prediction   versicolor virginica
    versicolor        470        30
    virginica          30       470

                Accuracy : 0.94            
                    95% CI : (0.9234, 0.9539)
        No Information Rate : 0.5             
        P-Value [Acc > NIR] : <2e-16          

                    Kappa : 0.88            
    Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1               

                Sensitivity : 0.94            
                Specificity : 0.94            
            Pos Pred Value : 0.94            
            Neg Pred Value : 0.94            
                Prevalence : 0.50            
            Detection Rate : 0.47            
    Detection Prevalence : 0.50            
        Balanced Accuracy : 0.94            

        'Positive' Class : versicolor
```

$^1$ For completeness: predicted class probabilities from your model are made either a "positive" prediction (usually above the threshold) or a "negative" prediction (usually below the threshold) by this.

**Update:**

As you just asked for how this would be done with e.g. `nnet()`, here's a minimal example:

```
# train model
library(nnet)
X <- nnet(x = iris[51:150,c(1,3)], y = class.ind(factor(iris[51:150,5])), size = 3, linout = F)

# predict class probabilities. you should *not* use the same samples as those used during training here (overfitting)
predicted <- predict(X, iris[51:150,c(1,3)])

# roc curve from class probabilities
library(pROC)
myRoc <- roc(predictor = predicted[,1], response = as.character(iris[51:150,5]), positive = 'versicolor')
plot(myRoc)
[...]
```

Please note that training on all data will lead to overfitting, so you should instead use techniques like cross validation and resampling (e.g. with the `caret` package, as shown above - there you would just need to set `method='nnet'` for using this model, and could provide hyperparameter in the `tuneGrid` parameter).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @geekoverdose. But where should I use the threshold value is it in the classifier ? for example in neural network classifier
X<-nnet(formula_use,data=traindata,size=3,Hess=TRUE,maxit=1000,rang=0.1,decay=5e-4,linout=FALSE) predicted<-predict(X,testdata,type="class",**threshold=0.25**) In this example I have used it in predict function. is it right ?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Yes, with using `X` within `predict()` later, *class probabilities* will be predicted for all samples you provide. Those can be used to plot a ROC curve then. BTW: you need to post such questions regarding a provided answer as comment to the answer, not as a separate answer (this answer will probably get deleted by a mod because of this). So please post anything else that might be unclear as comment.

Comment: Thanks. Since I queried as guest I cant Add Comment. I have one more question can I use this threshold parameter to other algorithms in predict ( ) ? like naive bayes, Random forest, logistic regression etc... will this have an effect on the TPR and FPR ?

Comment: @dev_55 I updated my answer to (probably) address what you asked here (see right above the "Update" too please).

Comment: Decision thresholds do not come from the data.  They must be defined externally, as the cost/loss/utility function usually involves variables that are not in the predictive model.  For that reason ROC curves do more harm than good.