# How can I plot an ROC curve?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, excel, auc

Given this simple data:

[image]

How can I plot an ROC curve in Microsoft Excel? Step by step instructions would be very helpful. I know my TPR is ~87% and my FPR is ~13%. How do I know where to set the intervals on my data though?

I've already looked at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve) but I'm not sure how to get the "score" of the data values.

Comment: You don't have enough information to plot an ROC curve, in Excel or anything else.  If this is all the infomration you have, then your task is impossible.

Comment: @PeterFlom How would I go about finding the predicted probabilities for each data point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the data you given, it is not possible to plot ROC curve.

This is because ROC curve needs **predicted probabilities for each data point**, so one can change the threshold to have different predicted classes. For each threshold, there re TPR and FPR associated with that, these are points in the ROC curve.

For your case, you do not have predicted probability for each data point, but have predicted label for **one selected threshold**, this will only be one point in the ROC curve. And generating the whole curve is not possible.

Comment: Would I have to use a logistic regression to find the predicted probabilities?

Comment: @fi12 most models can produce probabilities. not necessary to be logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

To plot roc curve you need not predicted classed, but predicted probabilities. Then at each possible threshold you calculate TPR and FPR and plot them.

In your case you have only one value for TPR and FPR, this means you can plot only a single point.