# SVM: achieving ROC curve by varying misclassification costs

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, roc

Assume that we have SVM model for binary classification with objective function as follows:
$$
min(\frac{1}{2}\omega\cdot\omega +C^{+}\sum_{i|y_{i}=+1}^{n}\xi_{i}\quad+C^{-}\sum_{i|y_{i}=-1}^{n}\xi_{i})
$$
After many times of running optimization with different misclassification costs($C^{+}$ and $C^{-}$) for testing part of one dataset,
I achieved a ROC(?) representation of the model:

[image: ROC(?) representation of the model]

Then, I decided to create logarithmic trendline for this set of points achieving:

[image: ROC(?) curve for the model]

After reading some questions, inter alia here, I came to a conclusion, that it 
is not a typical way to obtain a ROC curve for SVM. The questions are:

1. **Will I lie if I name it a (approximated) ROC curve for this model?**
2. **Was this a proper way to achieve ROC curve?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Will I lie if I name it a (approximated) ROC curve for this model?

Yes, this is definitely not a ROC curve. In addition what you are approximating is not the ROC curve.

> 2. Was this a proper way to achieve ROC curve?

No, what you did is has definitely nothing to do with a ROC curve.

A ROC curve is a curve that shows the monotone relationship between FPR and TPR as the *decision threshold* is varied. All the remaining variables like model parameters, the dataset on which FPR and TPR are computed, or meta parameters like (mis-)classification costs must remain constant. It is very easy to calculate exactly and doesn't require any approximation. Check out the question [Understanding ROC curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/105501/36682) on this site to see how to understand and properly build a ROC curve.