# What do the steps in ROC curve represent?

Tags: roc

I have got the following ROC for a binary classification task using scikit-learn's Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier.[image]

The graph shown here shows the ROC curve and has various step like shape. I want to know that what do these steps represent.

Comment: Did you check out some other ROC curve questions on this site? This one in particular should answer your question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve

Comment: Flagging as duplicate of [Understanding ROC curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve)