# How are True Negative and False Negative converted into True Positive and False Positive in ROC curve?

Tags: roc

I found the ROC explanation at this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve).  It states that the ROC curve is `TP` vs `FP`.

After the `score` has gone below `0.5`, all predictions are `negative`.  That makes them either `TN` or `FN`.  Thus, how does it make sense to continue drawing as the axes are stated as `TP` and `FP`?  I am really confused.

Comment: I think this is a situation where you're probably going to get better explanations for why your understanding is wrong the better you explain what your understanding is.

Comment: I found this very well explained [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jRBRDbJemM).  I suppose I got it wrong because of the lack of background theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The ROC curve shows the TPR and FPR as you change the threshold.** Your question posits that a classifier only has one TPR statistic and one FPR statistic, and that both of these statistics correspond to a threshold at 0.5.  This is a common misconception; there is no reason that the threshold must be 0.5. For each choice of threshold, there is a corresponding TPR and FPR statistic. The purpose of the ROC curve is to show the trade-off for each choice of threshold: as your TPR increases, so does your FPR, and vice-versa.

Comment: Goodness!  You caught the cause of my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

you vary the *threshold* which is used to determine positives and negatives, ie at threshold 0.5 we get a point (TP, FP)  which we plot, then at threshold 0.45 we get another point (TP, FP) which we plot, etc. These points make the ROC curve

Comment: I dont quite follow your explanation.  Say at point `1` (0.9) in that link, which (TP, FP) is acquired from that threshold value?

Comment: @CaTx The threshold is not graphed in the ROC curve.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: some ROCs feature the threshold e.g. as color. E.g. R package ROCR offers this option (and I recommend to use it, this additional information is often highly instructive).