# What is the independent value in an roc curve?

Tags: correlation, roc, dependent-variable

An ROC curve is plotted with (1-False Positive Rate) on the X-axis and the True Positive Rate on the Y-axis. However, the way in which each point of the curve is plotted is by first picking a cut-off probability value below which all samples are classified as negative and above which all are positive. And using this decision threshold, we get one point (TPR<sub>point 1</sub>, 1-FPR<sub>point 1</sub>). Doing this for multiple decision thresholds/cut-off probabilities, we can generate a 2-Dimensional ROC curve.

Does this mean that the true independent value is the cut-off probability and not the FPR as looking at the X-axis would suggest?

Comment: One of the uses of a ROC curve is to determine the threshold that gives the best classification result. See [this answer to the question "Understanding ROC curve"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105577/354273) for details.